# Running systrace directly from target device

Tags: android, adb, systrace

On our boards, USB is not yet up. We are experiencing some frame drop issues while doing video playback and we would like to see whats happening using systrace. Now, I have used systrace, but, with adb and related functionality working.

Is it possible to run systrace directly from the target device so that adb is not used at all?  In my opinion it should be, but am not able to find anything useful over web!

Thank you!

Comment: Look at the `systrace.py` command (it's written in Python). It's just running `atrace` with appropriate arguments, then streaming the result off of the device. You should be able to run atrace directly, directing the output to a file, and then pull the file off. At one point I added a `-o` flag to atrace to leave the output on the device, but I don't think I checked it in.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was able to get it to work.